# Django Issue: NameError with models.py file

Tags: django, django-models, syntax-error

I'm getting the for following error with my models file in Django.

"File "/home/mosmith/Projects/MasteringDjango/mysite/books/models.py", line 23, in Book
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
NameError: name 'Author' is not defined"

I've seen other issues with people are getting this but its due to not having the model defined before the call.

Here is my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models


    class Arthor(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
        email = models.EmailField()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.first_name

    class Publisher(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
        state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        website = models.URLField()

    class Book(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
        publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
        publication_date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: The model called Arthor, but the ManyToManyField to Author

Answer (score 0):

```
class Arthor(models.Model):
```

Change to AUTHOR, not ARTHOR.

Comment: Thanks, I dont know how I overlooked that.